# ldap search result reference message

Tags: active-directory, ldap, nested

I am trying to do nested group filter (i.e. trying to retrieve multiple groups to which user is a part of). I am able to get multiple entries to which this nested user is a part of. However, at the end i am also seeing one ldapsearchresref message as well.

My doubt is:
Is it a valid assumption to assume that as part of multiple entry search, you can assume ldapsearchresref message as the indicator of end of your search query (i.e. can you safely assume that for every search returning multiple search entries you will always receive ldapsearchresref indicating end of your search query result)?

Filter i am using to retrieve multiple entries is:

```
(&(objectclass=*)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=sam,dc=aaaldap,dc=com))
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it the part of this question you asked here also...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583021/ldap-nested-group-membership

Comment: Yes Rahul, sorry fr cluttering the forum with dulicate Q. But, i thought i would gain better visibility to this Q if i post it in a separate thread.

Answer (score 2):

You could receive a referral to almost any LDAP request.

If there was only one LDAP server and one partition, than you should NOT receive a referral.

You can not assume that there will always be a referral for every search request.

For each search Request you can expect the following:
http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Search%20Responses

Comment: Hi, I have only one ldap server but can you elaborate more on what you refer by one partition. Is there a way to ensure that on AD server, can i disable to ensure there is only one partition?

Comment: Query the rootDSE to find out. I am not positive how AD decides to do partitioning, but looking at my own 2003 server, I see four namingContexts: namingContexts: CN=Configuration,DC=mad,DC=willeke,DC=com
namingContexts: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mad,DC=willeke,DC=com
namingContexts: DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mad,DC=willeke,DC=com
namingContexts: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mad,DC=willeke,DC=com
namingContexts: DC=mad,DC=willeke,DC=com  where the defaultNamingContext: DC=mad,DC=willeke,DC=com
is the actual domain name.  The values are set by the server and AFIK, can not in AD be changed.